# iTunes refuses to authorise with my UK iTunes account now that I'm in Ireland

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, itunes-store

While I was in the UK on holiday I purchased a TV show from the iTunes UK site and got this on my iPod. It plays fine on the iPod. I would like to play these on my computer now I am back home in Ireland.

I have managed to get the files on to my PC's hard drive but when I go to play them, iTunes launches and says "this computer is not authorised to play this file". Even when I use my UK iTunes account to authorise it keeps saying "iTunes is unavailable at this time please try later" over and over again. Is it because I have an Engligh and Irish iTunes account?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple iTunes Store Accounts across different countries or regions. That's not causing the issue for you.

In iTunes, go to the "**Store > Authorize This Computer...**" menu option and sign in with the UK account to authorize the computer to play content from that store.

If it still does not work (or you have already authorized the computer), then it's likely a temporary error with connecting to the Apple iTunes server.

For more information, see:
[iTunes 11 for Windows: Authorize a computer to play iTunes Store purchases](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12511)